# java appletviewer wasn't displayed anything

Tags: java, html, graphics, applet, appletviewer

i'm creating the diagram to scale it's size to big,but while i'm running the appletviewer it wasn't displayed anything in the Applet window.

My code is below..check it

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

//<applet code="scale" width=500 height=500></applet>

public class scale extends Applet{
    int n=5;
    public void Paint(Graphics g)
    {
    int x[]={60,90,120,50,60};
    int y[]={70,50,140,100,70};
    int x1[]=new int[5];
    int y1[]=new int[5];
    int sx=4;
    int sy=2;
    Polygon p;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        x1[i]=x[i]*sx;
        y1[i]=y[i]*sy;

    }
    g.drawString("original Image : ",50,40);
    p=new Polygon(x,y,n);
    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.drawString("scaled Image : ",230,80);
    p=new Polygon(x1,y1,n);
    g.drawPolygon(p);
    }
}
```

the command i used to run is ,

```
C:\java>set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin"

C:\java>javac scale.java

C:\java>appletviewer scale.java
```

Comment: Check output for an exception.

Comment: Change `public void Paint(Graphics g)` to `@Override public void Paint(Graphics g)` for a compiler error that should be a tip. BTW - stop writing applets. They are dead.